# Best way to populate a base viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, viewmodel

I know there are two ways to populate a base modelview:

First way, using OnActionExecuted method:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result != null)
        {
            var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as BaseViewModel;

            if (model != null)
            {
                model.CurrentUser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CurrentUser"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Second way, property get accessor:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public string CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CurrentUser"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Which way is better? any pros/cons I'm missing?

Comment: There are plenty more ways than just the two you have listed, can you make your question a little more specific?

Comment: Generally speaking, I am looking for a way to share data across controllers. I retrieve the data once, save it to a cookie and subsequently access it using the base view model.
I'd appreciate if you can give another example.

Comment: @Mayrun - if its just a cookie, there's no need to put it in the base class, as a cookie can be access from a static context (e.g anywhere). Your not really *sharing* data, your just wrapping the code. It sound like your trying to re-use user data - why not stick it in the forms authentication ticket?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it the second way, as it'd be a little more clearer as to what the model value of `CurrentUser` is, without having to go poking around in the controllers.

Comment: What about writing an action filter that populates the base view model and then apply it only to certain controllers?